# How to install VMware Horizion Client with a CAC card reader for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, vmware, smartcard

I had issues installing VMWare Horizon Client onto Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have the CAC card reader recognized within the application.

I visited the VMWare website and searched through their documentation and I could not find a way to have the CAC card reader installed for a user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These steps are for the implementation of a user needing to use a CAC device to log into a VDI via VMWare Horizion Client. Also, these directions are written for the installation of VMWare Horizion Client 4.5.0 in an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS base OS.

1. Install the following from Synaptic *or* Software Manager

   - CoolKey
   - pcsc-lite
   - pcsc-ccid
   - perl-pcsc
   - pcsc-tools
2. After these items are installed, connect your CAC Card reader device to your PC
3. In a terminal window run the following command to ensure that your PC recognize your CAC card

   ```
   pcsc_scan
   ```
4. After you verify that the PC is reading your CAC card, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and close the window.
5. Download the [VMWare Horizion Client](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_horizon_clients/4_0). *Ensure you select the most current version.*
6. After you download install the following packages run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev v4l-utils pulseaudio
   ```
7. Now create symlinks to the latest versions

   ```
   sudo ln -s libudev.so.1.6.4 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
   sudo ln -s libffi.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5
   ```
8. Install the VMWare Horizion Client

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/
   chmod +x VMware-Horizon-Client-4.5.0-5650368.x64.bundle 
   sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.5.0-5650368.x64.bundle
   ```

   I selected the following options: Client Drive Redirection, USB Redirection
9. Make the following changes below to enable your CAC card reader to be recognized by the VMWare Horizion Client

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/vmware/view/pkcs11
   ```
10. Now create symlink for the CAC Card to be regonized by the client

    ```
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pkcs11/libcoolkeypk11.so /usr/lib/vmware/view/pkcs11/libgtop11dotnet.so
    ```